# Display div on page load having style display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display div on page load e.g."campaign-alert", but I am not able to do this .

This is sample code :

```
<div id="popup"> 
<div id="campaign-alert" style="display:none;">
.
.
.

</div>
</div>
```

I have tried this way as well :

```
document.getElementById('campaign-alert').style.display="";                  
document.getElementById('campaign-alert').style.display="block";
```

Can anybody help me in this ?

Comment: Where in the file did you put the Javascript? It has to run after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Why is this tagged jquery?

Comment: [Your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/webt9/).

Comment: any error in the console

Comment: Make sure your javascript is executed *after* the browser creates the "campaign-alert" div. This means you need to either wait until the document is "ready" (as some answers have posted), or put the `<script>` tag after the `<div>` tag in your HTML file. Once you do that, either of your two lines of code will work. The first line is preferable.

Comment: **[`See Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/dipeshbeckham/PpKAS/4/)**

Comment: Thank you all for your reply :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this. It will help you.

Using Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
              $("#campaign-alert").show();
        });
```

Using JavaScript

```
window.onload = function () {
     document.getElementById("campaign-alert").style.display = "block";
};
```

Comment: The OP tagged jQuery but he doesnt seem to use it, maybe you could had the pure JS solution (just in case).

Answer (score 4):

try the following

```
$(function () {
$("#campaign-alert").show();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You shaould try it using onload()

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="load()">
<div id="popup"> 
<div id="campaign-alert" style="display:none;">
.
.
.

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function load(){
document.getElementById('campaign-alert').style.display="block";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
              $("#campaign-alert").show();
        });
```

Where #campaign-alert selects the element with id campaign-alert

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using below function its working and tested.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function remove_style(all)
        {
            var i = all.length;
            var j, is_hidden;
            var attr =
            [
                'style'
            ];

            var attr_len = attr.length;

            console.log(attr_len);
            j = attr_len;

            all.removeAttribute(attr[0]);
        }

        function showdiv()
        {
            var all = document.getElementById('campaign-alert');
            remove_style(all);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="showdiv();">
<div id="popup"> 
<div id="campaign-alert" style="display:none;">
<h1>show me </h1>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    
    
    
 <div id="popup"> 
<div id="campaign-alert" style="display:none;">
.1
.2
.3

</div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("campaign-alert").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```