# automatic href to div when page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html code

```
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box">
<a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Here i am</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
        Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want popup window show when page is loaded. not waiting when i click to button. How to make with javascript or jquery? This example i found in [here](https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO)

Comment: Initially keep CSS property `display:none;`, `onClick` do `display:block;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display div on page load having style display:none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417256/display-div-on-page-load-having-style-displaynone)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417256/display-div-on-page-load-having-style-displaynone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use onload function.

HTML

```
<body onload="load()">
    <div id="popup"> 
       <div id="popUPAlert" style="display:none;">
          //Model content
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
function load(){
    document.getElementById('popUPAlert').style.display="block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you would want your popup to be initially hidden. Then when the content is loaded you would want to set the `display` property of the popup to `block`

CSS

```
#popup1 {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("popup1").style.display = "block";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbMBqE

## set `location.href`

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("load");
  location.href = "#popup1";
};
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("load");
  location.href = "#popup1";
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box">
 <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Here i am</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
   Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

use this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  yourFunction(url);
};

function yourFunction(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

In html you can also write :

```
<a href="popupex.html" onclick="return yourFunction('popupex.html')"
    >Link to popup</a>
```

Comment: write some code pls in yourFunction function) need optionally describe